# Output converted file in same folder as input file

Tags: windows, batch, libreoffice

I'm using the following command in a batch file, to convert to .odt format:

```
for /r %%i in (*.docx) do start /wait "" "c:\program files\libreoffice\program\soffice.exe" --headless --convert-to odt "%%i"
```

It works fine, but it outputs all files inside sub-folders in the parent folder.
What i would like, is to have the output file converted in the same sub-folder as the input file.
I tried it with `%%~dpni` and other variations without success.
LibreOffice has its own parameter `--outdir` to specify the output dir, but trying something like `--outdir .\` doesn't seem to work.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Change to the sub-folder before running soffice ...

Comment: There's hundreds of files that I would like to convert, a lot with the same name.

Comment: Are the files/folders appearing in the same directory as your batch file?

Comment: @Ecstasy yes, the batch file is in the parent folder and in there are hundreds sub-folders and in those are many docx files.

Comment: I am referring to the output of the batch file. Do the outputted items of the batch file appear in the same directory as the batch file?

Comment: Yes, and if there are similar named docx files, it is overwritten.

Comment: Try moving the batch file into the target folder, or have the batch file change directories before performing the operation.

Answer (score 0):

The forfiles command seems to get the job done, but it's a bit more cpu intensive:

```
forfiles /s /m "*.docx" /c "c:\progra~1\libreo~1\program\soffice.exe --headless --convert-to odt @file"
```